# How do I insert columns (missing dates) compared to two data frame in R?

Tags: r

First data frame(df1) is like the following:

```
Tickers       2020-01-07    2016-01-09
   A             0.54          N/A
   B              N/A          0.21
```

And second data frame(df2) is:

```
  NY          2020-01-06    2020-01-07   2020-01-08   2020-01-09   2020-01-10
   C              0.2          0.1           0.5          0.8         0.9
```

df1 should be final outcome. df1 must contain every column names(Dates) shown in df2, from 2020-01-06 to 2020-01-10. As you see df1 is missing "2020-01-06", "2020-01-08", 2020-01-10.(You can ignore df2's values) Also, every missing columns' value should be "N/A". The final outcome that I want to have is the following:

```
Tickers       2020-01-06    2020-01-07   2020-01-08   2020-01-09   2020-01-10
   A              N/A          0.54         N/A          N/A          N/A
   B              N/A          N/A          N/A          0.21         N/A
```

Up to now I've modified them in Excel and imported it again into R. It is very inefficient as you know.
How can I do this in R?

```
library(xts)
library(quantmod)

Tick <- c("BRZU")

df1 <-
  lapply(Tick,
         function(x) {
           try(getSplits(x, from= "2016-03-23", to="2016-03-29", src="yahoo"),
               silent = TRUE)
         })
names(split_test) <- Tick

# convert NA to xts object with date < 1900
df1 <-
  lapply(df1,
         function(x) {
           if (identical(x, NA)) xts(NA, .Date(-4e4)) else x
         })

# merge and remove pre-1900 date
df1 <- Reduce(merge, df1)["1900/"]

# set names
names(df1) <- Tick

df1 <- t(df1)
df1 <- as.data.frame(df1)

#Add columns missing dates
df2 <- getSymbols("^NYA", from= "2016-03-23", to="2016-03-29", auto.assign = F)
df2 <- t(df2)
df2 <- as.data.frame(df2)

df1[setdiff(names(df2[-1]), names(df1))] <- NA
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `setdiff` to get columns which are not present in `df1` and assign them as `NA`.

```
df1[setdiff(names(df2[-1]), names(df1))] <- NA
```

Comment: it does not work. I posted my real codes above. Is my df wrong?

Comment: @DongchulPark I think you don't need `-1` since `Tickers` is not a column in your dataset. `df1[setdiff(names(df2), names(df1))] <- NA` works for me by adding 2 new columns with `NA`.

Comment: It works! As you see a new column in df1(2016-03-23) is located at the end. Is there any way to reorder columns(oldest first)? I know how to sort after transpose, but df1 does not have first named column.

Comment: You can do `df1[order(as.Date(names(df1)))]`

Answer (score 0):

not elegant but this should do it

```
library(tidyr)
df1 <- gather(df1, key = 'Date', value = 'Number', 2:3)
df2 <- gather(df2, key = 'Date', value = 'Number', 2:6)

df3 <- rbind(df1, df2)

colnames(df3) <- c("Tickers", "Date", "Number")

df3 <- spread(df3, 'Date', 'Number')
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use `%in%` with `!`

```
df1[!(names(df2[-1]) %in% names(df1))] <- NA
```